Sci-fi book with a part-human, part-machine protagonist who lives for centuries to witness robots gain sentience and wage war on humans
I vaguely remember a sci-fi book I read with a long saga that starts with a human explorer who is fatally injured in a ship explosion and is then kept alive by being turned into a half-mechanical creature. He lives on for centuries, to witness robots gain sentience and wage war on humans.
At some point, both humans and robots are completely invested in exploring a gas giant (Jupiter, I think) where, in the upper levels, there are some sentient animals. In the end, the human-machine protagonist and the lead AI robot plummet to Jupiter's core, where they come to witness another, greater, older and all powerful sentience.

In roughly which year did you read this?

The story you're describing sounds like "The Medusa Chronicles," a science fiction novel by Stephen Baxter and Alastair Reynolds. It's a sequel to Arthur C. Clarke's novella "A Meeting with Medusa." The novel follows Howard Falcon, a human who is severely injured in a dirigible accident and transformed into a cyborg. Over the centuries, Falcon witnesses the rise of sentient machines and becomes entangled in the conflict between humans and robots. The climax of the story involves an exploration of Jupiter, where Falcon and a leading AI robot encounter a mysterious, ancient intelligence deep within the planet's atmosphere.
The book explores themes of humanity, machine intelligence, and the nature of consciousness, all while maintaining a sense of wonder about the universe.

Yess this is it

Is this LLM generated? The last sentence doesn't sound like something a human would write.

@JollyJoker: I agree - it certainly looks like a reply from ChatGPT or something like it. They always end a reply with some form of "summary"/"conclusion" of the answer

"Look at me.  Look at me.  You are in the sci-fi story now."

@JollyJoker Not necessarily AI. Could be a quote from the cover-text. Marketeers have been writing that sort of drivel on cover-texts since long before AI.
